# What was the reason behind using sqrt (square root) to name the nth root command?

Tags: math-mode, syntax, sqrt, scientific-notation

Clearly talking about:

> \sqrt[n]{x}

here!

Comment: A two dimensional square is a square. A three dimensional square is a cube. A four dimensional square (aka tesseract) is also often named either (four dimensional) cube or square, etc. The used glyph/sign is also still the one of a square root. The optional argument is just an add-on the that. So, yes, it is accurate. But if you like, you could, e.g., do `\let\negpower\sqrt` and use that. But I don't think, that it would be more accurate.

Comment: The main radical command was recently renamed from `\sqrt` to `\root` in context. That really makes more sense. (Of course `\sqrt` is kept as an alias...).

Comment: `\root[n]{x}`  would be better, but as the plainTeX `\root {n} \of {x}`  which is also in LaTeX  is probably used in various documents it is not really possible to change the definition. So you have to choose between the command with the odd name but a more latex like syntax and the more accurate name and the unusual `\of` syntax.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Note, that the author of TeX D. Knuth created the macro `\sqrt` only for square root in the basic plain TeX macro collection. The root with given power is provided by `\root number\of {argument}` in plain TeX. Both macros are based on the `\radical` TeX primitive which selects appropriate size of required symbol and adds vertical line over the given argument.

Only LaTeX introduced the optional argument in the `\sqrt` macro and the mention about `\root number\of` was removed from LaTeX documentation. But the `\root` macro works in LaTeX just like in plain TeX.

Comment: As much as we all know that you love plain TeX, mixing plain and LaTeX syntax is never advisable, and potentially error-prone if the LaTeX team decide to make some changes. So no, nobody should ever use `\root` with LaTeX.